# Passing null in AJAX request Rails interprets it as "null"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send an AJAX request via the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to a Rails 3 backend and I am stuck to a weird behavior. Take for example the following request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {a: null},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success!")
    }
});
```

which I am binding to a click event. Simple. What is happening is that Rack parses the URI encoded form parameters as `{"a" => "null"}` and I really want to get parsed as `{"a" => nil}`. Is there any non-hackish way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. If I pass `{a: undefined}` then params hash has no `a` key at all.

Comment: maybe you could set `data: {a: ''}`

Comment: Nope this passes `{"a"=>""}`

Comment: When `{"a"=>""}` is passed isn't it changed to nil in Rails' `params`, or key is missing totally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found the solution to this. I had to change the `$.ajax` call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({a: null}),
    processData: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log("success!")
    }
});
```

which does two important things. First it passes the content type header to JSON in order the request payload to automatically get parsed as JSON by Rack. The other one is that `processData` must be set to false in order to prevent the default jQuery behavior:

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: Just need contentType and JSON.stringify, since data is already a string after manual stringify. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: so if i need to upload a file my content type is set to `false` and my data is a `formData object` ... so how can i send null values in this case?